# what will happen if stopImmediate listener container property set to true in spring kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using Spring-kafka-3.0.6.
If I set the listener container property `stopImmediate` to true, then what will happen ?

In Docs, it is mentioned below:

`When the container is stopped, stop processing after the current record instead of after processing all the records from the previous poll.`

**But what will happen the rest of records which get polled from previous poll ?**

Comment: Those records remain in the topic until unretained / compacted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will be redelivered the next time the container is started.